# how to add video player in mvc4 which supports .wmv, .3gp, .avi and different other formats

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, avi, autostart, video-player, wmv

How to add video player in MVC 4 which supports .WMV, .3gp, .avi and different other formats?

I searched but only getting .mp4 and .ogg type files supported by video player only.

What can I do for other formats?

Comment: but i have videos in local folder then how to embed these videos in youtube.

Comment: i dont want to use you tube then will u pls suggest me any other solution.like video player and other thing..